# Get Full File Path During Enumeration

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm using the following code to enumerate a user selected path and populate an array with files names with specific extensions.

```
let enumerator:FileManager.DirectoryEnumerator = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: path)!

    while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? String {
    if ((element.hasSuffix("jpg"))||element.hasSuffix("playground")) {
    if(!self.yourArray.contains(element))
    {
    self.yourArray.append(element)
    }
    }
```

I need to get the complete file path to add the file to a processing queue.

Also how I can prevent the enumerator from exploring sub directories.

Please advice.

Comment: I am not able to understand your question please add more explanation  if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all use the URL related API, it's more versatile.

Unlike the `DirectoryEnumerator` `contentsOfDirectory` returns the URLs of all items in the directory without the subdirectories.

An easy solution is an array of path extensions and the `filter` function

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myUser/Pictures/")
let filterExtensions = ["jpg", "playground"]
do {
    self.yourArray = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        .filter{ filterExtensions.contains($0.pathExtension) }
    print(yourArray)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Be aware that `yourArray` will contain URLs, not string paths.

Comment: I guess Inorder to show the user the file path I need to convert the url to string `let url = NSURL(string: urlstring)`.. right?

Comment: No, to show the path get it with `url.path` and never use `URL(string:` for URLs related to the file system.

Comment: Seems like I need to create another string array using a while loop as I use this array as the datasource for a tree view i.e.: show the user the selected files.Now the TreeView is populated but it has suffix `file:///`

Comment: You can keep the file paths with `.filter({ filterExtensions.contains($0.pathExtension) }).map{ $0.path }`

Comment: Thanks.. I'm a Noob when It comes to SWIFT... just started learning few days back.Coming from C# Background.

Comment: Read the Language Guide. It's worth it. And don't try to apply C# patterns literally to Swift.

Comment: Tried this  `self.fileArray = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil).filter({ filterExtensions.contains($0.pathExtension) }).map{ $0.path }` But I get this error `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to closure result type 'URL'`

Comment: Now `fileArray` must be `[String]` because we converted all `URL`s to `String` with the `map` function. `URL` and `String` are different classes (actually structs)

Comment: @vadian you can also use the URL string initializer for local file resources as long as you include the url scheme, in this case the file://

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes of course, but it's a common mistake that the `string` initializer is used with a string path, there are many related questions.

Comment: @vadian yes but better to explain how to use it instead of just saying don’t use it.

Comment: Are we somehow getting items in subdirectories, or just the contents (1 level deep) of the directory passed to `contentsOfDirectory`? This is called a shallow search and is different to using the directory enumerator which provides all the files in all subdirectories.

Comment: @BenButterworth `contentsOfDirectory` one level, `DirectoryEnumerator` shallow search.

Comment: Okay thanks, I guess your answer is relevant to the question poster, but since I am trying to get **all** files in all subdirectories this won't work for me. I'll post my version of using directoryEnumerator which gets the full path

Answer (score 1):

### To use a directory enumerator:

This will allow you to get all the files in all subdirectories, not just the one level deep. Turn the path that you provided to `fileManager.enumerator(atPath: path)!` into a URL like below and then append the path provided by directory enumerator to this URL:

```swift
let directoryUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let pathUrl = directoryUrl.appendingPathComponent(element)
```

If I was writing your code, I would also do some renames/ improvements:

```swift
func main() {
    // Set up your variables
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let path = "/Users/username"
    var files = [URL]() // Using a URL instead of a path.

    let enumerator: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerator = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: path)!
    let directoryUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    while let filepath = enumerator.nextObject() as? String {
        if ((filepath.hasSuffix(".jpg")) || filepath.hasSuffix(".playground")) {
            let pathUrl = directoryUrl.appendingPathComponent(filepath)
            files.append(pathUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also [`enumerator(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/2765464-enumerator) which takes an URL and is more versatile.